# How do you split a hex string into bytes?

Tags: language-agnostic, numbers, hex, byte, bit-manipulation

Because hex is often used to represent things like RGBA color model data, I'm trying to find out how to go about taking a large *hex string* like 0x11AA22BB and split it into separate bytes. (So; 0x11, 0xAA, 0x22, and 0xBB chunks, essentially..). I know that each hex digit can be directly represented by four bits. But breaking up a chain of bits into smaller groups isn't something that I know how to do, either.

So, I'm sure that there is probably a simple answer to this. I'm sure it probably has something to do with casting it to an array of single bytes, or using bitwise operators or something, but I can't figure it out. I know that there is also an issue of endianness and how the bytes are organizes (RGBA, ARBG, ABGR, etc.), but right now I'm just looking to understand how to do the splitting so I can get a general understanding of how it works. I'm using C++ but I think that this might not necessarily be specific to that language.

So, to reiterate; *How does one take a large hex string like 0x11AA22BB and split it into 0x11, 0xAA, 0x22, 0xBB?*

Comment: What do you mean by "hex number"? A string?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "hex number" in a computer. You have a textual representation of a binary value. You parse the string and do the math. Or do you mean you have an `int` and want to read each byte?

Comment: I've changed my terminology to 'string', thanks for the info. I do realize that all numbers in a computer are representations of binary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two ways are mod/div and shift/mask, but both are actually the same way.

mod/div:

```
num = 0x11aa22bb
while num > 0:
  byte = num % 0x100
  print hex(byte)
  num //= 0x100
```

shift/mask:

```
num = 0x11aa22bb
while num > 0:
  byte = num & 0xff
  print hex(byte)
  num >>=8
```

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks for the straightforward answer, Ignacio. So it's really very similar to how one would go about splitting a decimal number into tens, hundreds, thousands, etc. That makes perfect sense to me, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind stepping away from C++ and you own a Linux machine, you could sed it using:

> sed 's/0x/ /g' file.hex | sed 's/[a-fA-F0-9]{2}/0x& /g' | tr -s ' '

First command removes 0x prefixes and replaces them by spaces, the second command splits the sequences in bytes and adds the prefixes to each part. The last command squeezes white spaces.

Note that you can use this on stdin by removing the filename (file.hex).

Answer (score 0):

```
void splitByte(unsigned char * split, unsigned int a,int quantBytes)
{
  unsigned char aux;
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<quantBytes;i++)
  {
      split[i]=a&0x00FF; 
      a=(a>>8);
  }
  for(i=0;i<quantBytes-1;i++)
  {
      aux = split[i];
      split[i] = split[quantBytes-i-1];
      split[quantBytes-i-1] = aux;

  }
}
```

In the main: unsigned char split[4]; splitByte(split, 0xffffffff, 4);**strong text**